# How to configure guard-rspec to ignore a directory when all the test cases are running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Lets say I have three directors in my spec folder; features, test, integration.
When I run `bundle exec guard` and press enter, is there a way that I can configure my Guardfile to ignore the test cases that are located in the integrations directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Guardfile, you can specify [the command to use when running all specs](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#list-of-available-options). You can specify an [rSpec command with a file exclude pattern](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/configuration/exclude-pattern) to run everything but the integration specs:

```
guard :rspec,
      cmd: 'bundle exec rspec', 
      run_all: { cmd: 'bundle exec rspec --exclude-pattern "**/integrations/*_spec.rb"' } do
  # ...
end
```

You might have to tweak this a bit depending on what you need exactly, see the links in the answer for the relevant bits of documentation.